# DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged - Cancel the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a panel, which contains a ListView with an itemTemplate which contains for each element a dropdowlist, two textboxes and one delete's button.

Each dropdownlist of each Listview elements contains the same datas, a list of values from a datasource, but the selected values are differents in differents rows. Certains values can be the same, it depends of a constraint.

This constraint, for some elements from my dropdownlist, is that i can have the same value on two rows.

I bound my dropdownlist with OnSelectedIndexChanged event and autoPostback to True in the design :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLinkToDestinationParent" CssClass="ddl-link-to ddl-link-to-child" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlNewConsumptionLinkToDestinationParent_OnSelectedIndexChanged" data-headcount='<%# Eval("HeadCount") %>' />
```

I pass in my event (server side).

```
var ddl = sender as DropDownList;

        if (IsDestinationSelected(ddl))
        {
            // Display error message
            // cancel the selection of my dropdownlist or select another value...

        }
```

The method IsDestinationSelected permit to know if my dropdownlist with a this value and with the constraint is found. If true, i want to cancel my selected item of my dropdownlist

What can i write after the error message ?

I try some solutions, but nothing interessant... (320 is juste for test, but is a list item) :

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByValue("320"));
```

This is my list item :

```
<select name="ctl00$Main$lvSetConsumptionsSite$ctrl1$ddlLinkToDestinationParent" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$Main$lvSetConsumptionsSite$ctrl1$ddlLinkToDestinationParent\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_Main_lvSetConsumptionsSite_ctrl1_ddlLinkToDestinationParent" class="ddl-link-to ddl-link-to-child" data-headcount="0">
    <option value="">--- Type de consom° ---</option>
    <option value="870">petit dejeuner 1 siege</option>
    <option value="877">petit dejeuner 2 (siege)</option>
    <option value="133">dejeuner 1 siege</option>
    <option value="26">dejeuner 2 (siege)</option>
    <option value="237">dejeuner 3 (siege)</option>
    <option value="238">dejeuner 4 (siege)</option>
    <option value="239">dejeuner 5 (siege)</option>
    <option value="241">dejeuner 6 (siege)</option>
    <option value="288">dejeuner 7 (siege)</option>
    <option value="852">pique nique (gouter 1 siege)</option>
    <option value="507">diner 1 (siege)</option>
    <option value="883">test 20/09 (diner - siege)</option>
    <option value="136">Goûter 2 (siege)</option>
    <option value="134">Resident (pas dans CM)</option>
    <option value="24">pertes (diner - siege)</option>
    <option value="25">cessions (pas dans CM)</option>
    <option value="201">Taxes et Frais divers (pas dans CM)</option>
    <option value="227">Emballages (consignes et déconsignes)</option>
    <option value="135">Diners de luxe (pas dans CM)</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="320">ajustement de stock</option>
    <option value="334">autre</option>
    <option value="745">HAPPY</option>
    <option value="876">consommation</option>
    <option value="802">test AB Cons 3105 01</option>
    <option value="869">panier repas (pas dans CM)</option>
    <option value="915">1 dest. siege</option>
    <option value="953">collation de 11h</option>

</select>
```

But when i try to change my value or my item, i call another time my event, but with the value selected, also infinite loop...

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

In your event handler just do something like this:

```
ddl.ClearSelection();
```

Also, make sure you databind the values in `if(!isPostBack)` block in Page_Load to prevent unexpected results.

***Update after the comments:***

As I've said, you need some kind of persistence of the original values. There are several ways of accomplishing this:

**1.)** in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event do your compare operation, and if he can't perform it, query the database to get the original value and use it to select it in the dropdownlist

**2.)** store these original values when you bind the dropdownlists, maybe in a dictionary like this:

```
var collectionToBindTo = Db.GetMyItems();
Dictionary<int, string> originalValues; 
foreach (var item in collectionToBindTo)
{
    originalValues.Add(item.Id, item.SomeValue);
} 
dropdownlist.DataSource = collectionToBindTo;
dropdownlist.DataBind();
// now add the collection to the session
```

where the int is the key (probably Id of the item?) and the string is the original value. Then you will have to store this collection in Session for instance, so you can retrieve it between the postbacks without having to requery the database.

I guess you're using an element DataSource in your aspx file, so the second would be quite hard for you to do. What you could do instead is to use the first option, which is really easy if you don't hit the database too often.

Hope it makes sense. It isn't a copy&paste solution, you need to alter these ideas to fit your needs.

Comment: Ok for ClearSelection, I think it oculd be the solution, but the prolem still remains. Indeed, var ddl = sender as DropDownList; contains the new selected value and not the old value I try to get.

Comment: @blasil64, what old value you want to get? Your question is not really clear, or maybe I just don't get it. You have a listview full of items, each item has its dropdownlist with identical items. User changes the selection in the dropdownlist, what do you want to do? Check if the user can perform the operation and if not, rollback the change? Of course that you get the new value after the postback, that's the whole reason of using this event. If you need to get some old value, you need some way of persisting/figuring it out.

Comment: You undersatnd what I expect. My dropdownlist contains values and there is a selected value at the moment, this is my 'old value'. I want to change the selected item, i choose a 'new value'. I pass in my event. If all my rules and contraints are respected, it's ok. Either, i want to rollback (have the old value as selected). Is it clear ? Thanks for help !

Comment: @blasil64, we'll see if that's clear :) See my update, hope it works for you.